# Detect Snackbar being dismissed (not onDimissed)

Tags: android-snackbar

I have a switch between two states that upon click shows a snackbar with the current state. If a user quickly switches state back an forth, possibly many snackbars are queued that will show up after one another, indicating either of the states while the other may be active. This may confuse the user, so I figured I'd dismiss the other state's snackbar upon creation of a new one.

To achieve this I call the old snackbar's `dismiss()` method. There's a problem with this: when I switch state, i.e., when I `dismiss()` the old and `show()` the new snackbar while the old snackbar was already in its dismiss animation, the `dismiss()` call forces the animation to restart, creating a graphical glitch (the almost dismissed old snackbar is re-dismissed). Note that the old snackbar's dismiss animation can be initiated by myself (calling `dismiss()`) or by the system (after timeout).

A solution would be to detect that a snackbar is being or about to be dismissed. There is the `Snackbar.Callback` class `onDismissed()` method, but that method is only called *after* the dismiss animation finishes. I'd like to detect the snackbar *before* or *during* the dismissal. The boolean method `isShown()` of class `BaseTransientBottomBar` is of no use either: the snackbar is shown until the dismissal finishes.

I also tried to get the snackbar's `View` and add an `OnLayoutChangeListener`, but that only listens to the creation of the snackbar and is not used upon dismissal.

How can I detect a snackbar about to be / being dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss the snackbar, you could save the current time:

```
long snackbarDismissStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then, to check if the snackbar is currently being dismissed, do:

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() < snackbarDismissStartTime + 250)
{
   // snackbar is currently being dismissed
}
```

250 is the number of milliseconds it takes for the snackbar animation to complete as specified by the `BaseTransientBottomBar` constant `ANIMATION_DURATION`.  Of course, there is no guarantee that this value won't changed in the future.

You also may want to add a fudge factor of about 100ms (just what it seems to need from my own experience), if you want to be absolutely sure the dismissal has finished.

Comment: This will detect a snackbar still being dismissed after I call `dismiss()`, which is one part of the problem. A different problem is a dismiss being initiated by the system after spontaneous timeout; in that case I don't call `dismiss()` on the old snackbar, but the system does. What is nice is that I know when, because I can specify the snackbar's duration. So, with that information, your answer could be extended to work for any snackbar. It may even be possible to override `dismiss()` to include this check, but I don't know for sure as I cannot check right now. I've edited to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library called SnackProgressBar. It includes an extended queuing system which might be helpful. You can clear all the stacked SnackProgressBar queue via a simple `clearAll()` call, before showing your new SnackProgressBar. Hope it solves your problem.

https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar